# ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from partially initialized module 'DatabaseService' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

I am following this [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one) to add a one-to-one mapping using sqlalchemy, this is my parent part code:

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    child = relationship('ArticleContent', uselist=False, back_populates="article")
```

and this is my child part code:

```
class ArticleContent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article_content'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    article = relationship('Article', back_populates="article_content")
```

and this is the base part code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from dolphin.common.db.ArticleContent import ArticleContent
from dolphin.common.db.Article import Article

Base = declarative_base(class_registry={
     "articleContent": ArticleContent,
     "article": Article
})


class DatabaseService:
    url = "postgresql://postgres:postgresjiang123456@postgres.dolphin.com:5432/dolphin"
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=False, encoding="utf-8")
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
```

now when I run this code, it tell me circle reference:

```
  File "/home/dolphin/source-share/source/dolphin/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/DatabaseService.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dolphin.common.db.ArticleContent import ArticleContent
  File "/home/dolphin/apps/pycharm-community-2020.2.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 114, in patched_import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dolphin/source-share/source/dolphin/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/ArticleContent.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dolphin.common.db.DatabaseService import Base
ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from partially initialized module 'dolphin.common.db.DatabaseService' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/dolphin/source-share/source/dolphin/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/DatabaseService.py)
```

I have read official docs again and again, read another questiones and tweak my code, but still not work, where am I going wrong? what should I do to make it works? this is my filename tree:

[image]

Comment: Did You Have Made a file with the same name as you import

Comment: Yes, the filename is the class name, the two names are the same. @TanayMishra

Comment: So try rename it then